# Cannot start tomcat services via playbook invoked using jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ansible

I have created a playbook to copy tomcat package, change port and copy the .war from my build and deploy it in  tomcat server and start the tomcat services. 
when i executed my playbook from terminal it is working fine and tomcat services are started .

But when I invoke the playbook from Jenkins it did all the tasks except starting tomcat services though Jenkins it showing as changed . I 've provided my simple playbook and Jenkins console output.

#### CONSOLE OUTPUT:

```
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-02-15T20:13:46+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 27M/214M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ILP2_Clean_Pkg/Bookstore/ILP_Bookstore/pom.xml to devops.ilp1/ILP/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ILP-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ILP2_Clean_Pkg/Bookstore/ILP_Bookstore/target/ILP_Bookstore.war to devops.ilp1/ILP/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/ILP-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war
channel stopped
[ILP2_Clean_Pkg] $ sshpass ******** /usr/bin/ansible-playbook /var/lib/jenkins/roles/tomcat/main.yaml -i /var/lib/jenkins/ansiserver -f 5 -u jenkins -k

PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************

ok: [localhost]

TASK [/var/lib/jenkins/roles/tomcat : to unarchive tar tomcat] *****************

changed: [localhost]

TASK [/var/lib/jenkins/roles/tomcat : to change port number] *******************

changed: [localhost]

TASK [/var/lib/jenkins/roles/tomcat : to copy the war source file] *************

ok: [localhost]

TASK [/var/lib/jenkins/roles/tomcat : to add tomcat users] *********************

changed: [localhost]

TASK [/var/lib/jenkins/roles/tomcat : to start tomcat services] ****************

changed: [localhost]

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=6    changed=4    unreachable=0    failed=0   

ILP2_BookStore is disabled. Triggering skipped
ILP2_Inttesting_Scan is disabled. Triggering skipped
Finished: SUCCESS
```

#### PLAYBOOK

```
cat /var/lib/jenkins/roles/tomcat/main.yaml
- hosts: localhost
  become: yes
  become_user: jenkins 
  roles:
   - /var/lib/jenkins/roles/tomcat
root@:/etc/systemd# cat /var/lib/jenkins/roles/tomcat/tasks/main.yaml
- name: to unarchive tar tomcat 
  unarchive:
     src: apache-tomcat-8.5.38.tar.gz
     dest: "{{tomcat}}"
- name: to change port number 
  template:
     src: server.xml.j2
     dest: "{{tomcat}}/apache-tomcat-8.5.38/conf/server.xml"
- name: to copy the war source file 
  copy:
    src:  /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ILP_BookStore/target/ILP_Bookstore.war
    dest: "{{tomcat}}/apache-tomcat-8.5.38/webapps/"
- name: to add tomcat users
  template:
    src: tomcat-users.xml.j2
    dest: "{{tomcat}}/apache-tomcat-8.5.38/conf/tomcat-users.xml"
- name: to start tomcat services
  shell: "{{tomcat}}/apache-tomcat-8.5.38/bin/startup.sh"

root@:/etc/systemd# cat /var/lib/jenkins/roles/tomcat/vars/main.yaml
tomcat: /home/osgdev/ansilab/tomcat/
tomcat_port: 12345
root@:/etc/systemd# ls -ld  /var/lib/jenkins/roles/tomcat/vars/files/
ls: cannot access '/var/lib/jenkins/roles/tomcat/vars/files/': No such file or directory
root@:/etc/systemd#
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to the [Jenkins Process Tree Killer](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller).  TL;DR: daemons or other long-lived background processes started by a Jenkins build will be killed when that build finishes, unless the Process Tree Killer is disabled.

To disable the Process Tree Killer, follow the directions in the docs I linked to you.  Based on the information you've posted in your question, I believe the best way for you to disable it is to alter the environment variable `BUILD_ID` before starting up any daemons.

See also this [same question asked on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39169457/how-to-tell-jenkins-not-to-kill-processes-after-successful-execution-of-job-in-m).