# Jenkinsfile pipeline for running vagrant up

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant, jenkins

I am encountering a strange issue, when i run vagrant up, the virtual machine builds up fine and works as intended, but when I run the same command in a Jenkinsfile pipeline, after the build is completed, the virtual machine shutsdown with a created log.

```
Log created: 2021-01-15T12:32:44.144568000Z
Process ID:  9678 (0x25ce)
Parent PID:  1 (0x1)
Executable:  /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxSVC
Arg[0]: /usr/lib/virtualbox/VBoxSVC
Arg[1]: --auto-shutdown
AddRef: illegal refcnt=3221225469 state=2
```

This is the pipeline code for vagrant

```
stage('Run Vagrant'){
    sh 'cd /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/jenkins-file_master/ansible/; vagrant up'
}
```

Jenkins config is set for the same user, so that the environment is the same.

```
# user and group to be invoked as (default to jenkins)
JENKINS_USER=myusername
JENKINS_GROUP="adm cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin lxd sambashare docker vboxusers"
```

Comment: This question is the same question as in https://superuser.com/questions/1406120/cannot-start-tomcat-services-via-playbook-invoked-using-jenkins/1406235#1406235, but the system won't let me flag as duplicate because that question has received very little attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're running into the Process Tree Killer, a "feature" of Jenkins which kills all processes started by a build when that build terminates.  The intention is to prevent Jenkins builds from starting services, daemons, or other long-lived processes which may affect other builds or the Jenkins machine itself.

There are a couple ways to disable this feature, as stated in the wiki and this SO question:

- https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/ProcessTreeKiller
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39169457/how-to-tell-jenkins-not-to-kill-processes-after-successful-execution-of-job-in-m

Those fixes are:

- Set the Java parameter `-Dhudson.util.ProcessTree.disable=true` on your Jenkins process (personally, I've had the best luck with this solution)
- During your build, change the value of the environment variable `BUILD_ID` (for Freestyle and other non-Pipeline jobs) or `JENKINS_NODE_COOKIE` (for Pipeline jobs)